# Eclipse Counterclockwise plugin autocomplete not working

Tags: eclipse, clojure, content-assist, counterclockwise

I have installed Eclipse with the counterclockwise plugin for Clojure development

When I type, no auto-complete comes up. Pressing Ctrl+Space has no effect in Clojure mode, but if I make a Java project it works fine.

I know that eclipse is connected properly to the leiningen repl because the "jump to definition" feature is working fine.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but it's a [bug in the current version of Counterclockwise](https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/issues/873).

Comment: Although I tried it with eclipse luna and had the same problem

Comment: For Luna and other pre-Neon Eclipses, you can downgrade to  0.34.0.STABLE001 version of the plugin, see https://github.com/laurentpetit/ccw/issues/866